# ClassCastException - Hibernate process results

Tags: java, hibernate

I get the below error, while trying to execute a SQL Query using Hibernate.

Error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to model.Emp1000
    at com.firsthb.StoreData.selectoperation_sql(StoreData.java:107)
    at com.firsthb.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:43)
```

Hibernate code:-

```
    Query sqlquery1 = session.createSQLQuery("Select  a.id, a.firstName, a.lastName, b.emp_dept from Emp1000 a inner join emp_dept b on a.id = b.emp_id");

List<Emp1000> sqllist1 = sqlquery1.list();

for (Emp1000 emp : sqllist1) {
    System.out.println(emp.getFirstName());
}
```

Employee persistent class:-

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the emp1000 database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Emp1000.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Emp1000 e")
public class Emp1000 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to EmpDept
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="emp1000", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<EmpDept> empDepts;

    public Emp1000() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public List<EmpDept> getEmpDepts() {
        return this.empDepts;
    }

    public void setEmpDepts(List<EmpDept> empDepts) {
        this.empDepts = empDepts;
    }

    public EmpDept addEmpDept(EmpDept empDept) {
        getEmpDepts().add(empDept);
        empDept.setEmp1000(this);

        return empDept;
    }

    public EmpDept removeEmpDept(EmpDept empDept) {
        getEmpDepts().remove(empDept);
        empDept.setEmp1000(null);

        return empDept;
    }

}
```

Question:-

The persistent class Emp1000 exactly matches the query execution. why would I get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you are trying to fetch

```
Select  a.id, a.firstName, a.lastName, b.emp_dept from Emp1000 a inner join emp_dept b on a.id = b.emp_id
```

Which is actually returning attributes of two different objects.  What you want is custom fields from two different entities. You can achieve this using this

```
Query query = session.createQuery("Select  a.id, a.firstName, a.lastName, b.emp_dept from Emp1000 a inner join emp_dept b on a.id = b.emp_id");
List<Object[]> rows = query.list();
```

And then iterate over this list of Object[] as follow:

```
for (Object[] row: rows) {
 System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
 System.out.println("id: " + row[0]);
 System.out.println("first name: " + row[1]);
 System.out.println("last name: " + row[2]);
 System.out.println("department: " + row[3]);
}
```

You are getting this error because the it tries to convert the object[] to the specific Entity object.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `EmpDept` is another entity.

You cannot join an entity `Emp1000` with a table `emp_dept`

Try to do something like:

```
Select a.id, a.firstName, a.lastName, b.department from Emp1000 a inner join EmpDept b on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: "Select  a.id, a.firstName, a.lastName, b.dept from Emp1000 a inner join emp_dept b on a.id = b.emp_id" -- this query works fine in the sqleditor. Emp1000 and emp_dept are both tables..How can I get the result back as a collection of entities?

Comment: ok, that's right. I don't pay attention in the returned data type that the code expects `List<Emp1000>`